# NPM Permission Error when installing packages on external drive

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm getting a permission error when I try to run `npm install` inside a project that's on my external SSD drive. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to use npm on the projects store at the drive.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../which/bin/node-which
npm ERR! dest /media/caio/SSD-1TB/projetos/pessoais/BlackBox/src/BlackBox.Electron/node_modules/.bin/node-which
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../which/bin/node-which' -> '/media/caio/SSD-1TB/projetos/pessoais/BlackBox/src/BlackBox.Electron/node_modules/.bin/node-which'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../which/bin/node-which' -> '/media/caio/SSD-1TB/projetos/pessoais/BlackBox/src/BlackBox.Electron/node_modules/.bin/node-which'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../which/bin/node-which',
npm ERR!   dest: '/media/caio/SSD-1TB/projetos/pessoais/BlackBox/src/BlackBox.Electron/node_modules/.bin/node-which'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-03-07T18_48_48_375Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: i have same issue did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if anyone has this problem - My problem was my drive was `exFAT` which doesn't support symlinks - I formatted it to ntfs and it fixed it.

found it in the comments here:

> "Most external filesystems don't support symlinks. You'll need to format it in one that does, such as ext2/3/4,, btrfs, zfs, ufs,and somewhat limited ntfs with smart awareness of it"
> https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/owyvov/could_not_create_symlink_when_copying_node/